# Does the question "How funny is John?" imply that John is funny?

Tags: meaning, questions, semantics

I have recently read that questions of the type "How x is y?" might imply different things depending on the adjective used. For example, by asking the question in (1), we have the idea that the speaker thinks John is short. This would not happen if the speaker used the adjective 'tall' instead of 'short' - so question (2) does not presuppose that John is tall.

(1) How short is John?

(2) How tall is John?

My question is this: if I take pairs of adjectives that talk about opinion or personal taste, such as funny/boring and pretty/ugly, does this pattern hold? When someone asks the questions (3)-(6), does it look like this person thinks John is in fact funny (number (3)), boring (number (4)), pretty (number (5)), and ugly (number (6))? Or is it possible to use these questions to ask for a piece of information with no prior knowledge on whether John is funny, boring, pretty, or ugly?

(3) How funny is John?

(4) How boring is John?

(5) How pretty is John?

(6) How ugly is John?

Thanks!